# facebook social plugin Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-iframe, same-origin-policy

First time asking....
I'm trying to display FACEBOOK SOCIAL PLUGIN on my website, the JS SDK does not display it... so I'm using de Iframe code instead of the JS...

Now I can see the social plugin on my site, but there are two console errors related to the FB social plugin...

These are:

Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/xti.php?xt=AZVYDwBjs0JR45Ocjz7JHYmthKwqlT5FWf9AA_3HWcvlAhILnzBNqKbsLlHEU-LXB-NRyrni3CuD6pBEqGaWwgOuP3SGYVaRm2mMirly8OM74oGRKmiIxchNcgEdGeaMmDoEWv9AI8MU_uGqRos1OGcGLOqoKu0daxwG2-SiHiCQY_KEfZUPwiMoCG_wKrz64r49T-1i09u7rmXq9WhJXdGqSZ2XT8B7px6tWuW3zHUxZWDgAqsoVCkJJ26wrMcXHc1KxhEdXGtMwyrtDeBwJBZnxhHrSWfPv2XODlkVK1IlR_F-iN2Pan2v0JJgUXcDyvU7QIbujcsO7KEPyMvzBVjXYwVZfjA_MMrUaL76FzLzSneBx304VlSULhGTNi4LkSkcdgiaJAuWqK0CuTI_4g6u5z2B8gzBPQNA_LgTJGCrFT4WMwEBAgRfI65x7ACgO_BBPRhSmK3k8_NxKmn8UauU2B6w6vzipbP8hDwjZ_0aFQudaG0LEsVttn6-ftCGXLFxQaZUM2tZspxUZAkLmlxC5vLaabeJHQtwf9rNU4_rWgwaMucQfJttSG-825uCeMZbjpJTu7iOLmdM-DvQluJWNtNIOHLTtswSsRjeqpVkWqKN3NrORaQq0sBVTE_w01SYJ9wI7rd02f1YNU_HR5h__UsxZKHzfLvWeuJ4OYhb0ki22eRFEYAQRpWy1Rqqn9Y&isv=1&cts=1512670189&csp' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

AND THE OTHER CONSOLE ERROR LOG IS:

Uncaught (in promise) Objectmessage: "Request aborted."name: "abort"status: 0type: "aborted"url: "https://video.fpbc1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t42.1790-2/24345950_2038974836333175_177521984870023168_n.mp4?efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6ImRhc2hfdjRfaHE0X2ZyYWdfMl92aWRlbyJ9&oh=0c0c6b95a96f7e4d531cb200c90694b9&oe=5A29B0B4&bytestart=78035&byteend=320616"**proto**: Object

and the code I'm using for displaying the social plugin is the one that facebook provides at:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

Example code is:

Please help me... I dont know what to do in order to get rid of these errors.... :C

Comment: EXAMPLE IFRAME CODE:

<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="340" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

Comment: Do those errors actually affect the functionality of the plugin on your site?

Comment: not really... everything works fine, its just the error message :/

Comment: I am facing the same problem and my facebook app is not proceeding ahead by a popup window